# How to use a google map DrawingManager with AngularJS UI.Map directive?

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, angular-ui

I would like to interact with a Google Map in an AngularJS application.
The UI.Map directive seems to be straightforward and is simple to use.
For my use case I need to use a map to trigger a geospatial search by drawing a polygon on the map.

I haven't found a way to add a drawing control using the UI.Map directive.

Based on the example and documentation of the UI.Map directive http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-map/ I haven't managed to figure out whether or how his is already supported by the UI.Map directive.

In a non angular app I use a DrawingManager to create the control that for drawing a polygon:

```
 var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({…});
 drawingManager.setMap(map);
```

The question how can access to the DrawingManager when using the UI.Map directive?

Anybody out there who can provide some help in this regard?

Comment: How did you end up resolving this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [angular-google-maps](https://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api) directive and its drawing-manager sub-directive.

> The drawing-manager directive is used to turn on the drawing manager
>   GUI which allow the user to place their own markers, polygons, etc on
>   the map

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though there should be a directive that lets you set uiMapPolygon as an element. That's what I gather from the documentation. Unfortunately, I couldn't get that to work as expected so I used a technique that's triggered by the map-tilesloaded UI event.

```
        <div ui-map="nggMap" ui-options="mapOptions" ui-event="{ 'map-tilesloaded' : 'drawBoundaries()' }" class="map-canvas"></div>
```

And then in your controller, first define the firstLoad variable to true. Then, insert your function:

```
        var firstLoad = true;

        $scope.drawBoundaries = function() {
            if (firstLoad)
            {
                var shapeOptions = {
                  strokeWeight: 1,
                  strokeOpacity: 1,
                  fillOpacity: 0.2,
                  editable: false,
                  clickable: false,
                  strokeColor: '#3399FF',
                  fillColor: '#3399FF'
                };

                var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
                  drawingMode: null,
                  drawingControlOptions: {drawingModes: [google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON]},
                  polygonOptions: shapeOptions,
                  map: $scope.nggMap
                }); 

                firstLoad = false;
            }
        }
```